# How to get hour of the year from a datetime in R?

Tags: r, lubridate

I am surprised that the `lubridate` package doesn't have this function.
What I am looking for is something like `yday(x)` which gives day of year but I want `yhour(x)` that would return `1` for `2020-01-01 01:00:00`, `2` for `2020-01-01 02:00:00` and so on all the way up to 8760 for a non-leap year.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own function to calculate it :

```
library(lubridate)
yhour <- function(time) {
  (yday(time) - 1) * 24 + hour(time)
}
yhour(as.POSIXct('2020-01-01 08:00:00'))
#[1] 8
```

which can be written in base R as :

```
yhour <- function(time) {
  (as.integer(format(time, '%j')) - 1) * 24 + as.integer(format(time, '%H'))
}
```

The logic here is to get the day of the year, subtract 1 day from it multiply by 24 and add today's hour to it.

Comment: Right...nice one!